# Unresolved symbol "pthread_condattr_setclock" in android other than 5.0

Tags: android, native

I am using "**pthread_condattr_setclock**" in one of my native shared library. Building is fine, but when I load the native library in android application using **System.loadLibrary** app is getting terminated throwing exception

**failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "pthread_condattr_setclock" referenced by abcd.so**

This exception I am not getting when I run my application in android 5.0, but in other android versions.

Anybody has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Android did use non-standard functions when it came to `pthread_condattr` functions. Even when the declarations for the standard ones are there in the pthread.h file of my NDK directory, Android complains about them not being defined if I use a version prior to API level 21 too.

Before Android 5.0, one could use other non-standard functions for waiting using the monotonic clock, for example (`pthread_cond_timedwait_monotonic_np`), but they have been removed in Android 5.0. I do not know why the functions don't work when they are declared and (AFAIK) are not officially unsupported, but it looks like the non-standard methods of the `pthread_condattr` family need to be used if on an Android version prior to 5.0.

See for example [here](https://github.com/ljbade/libuv-1/commit/a23d5b4f7a0f803e23ff9df6a57ee416d9b31610).